# boost asio: maintaining a list of connected clients

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm looking for the best way to modify the Boost Asio [HTTP Server 3 example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) to maintain a list of the currently connected clients.

If I modify server.hpp from the example as:

```
class server : private boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    typedef std::vector< connection_ptr > ConnectionList;

    // ...

    ConnectionList::const_iterator GetClientList() const
    {
        return connection_list_.begin();
    };

    void handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& e)
    {
        if (!e)
        {
            connection_list_.push_back( new_connection_ );
            new_connection_->start();
            // ...
        }
    }

private:
    ConnectionList connection_list_;
};
```

Then I mess up the lifetime of the connection object such that it doesn't go out of scope and disconnect from the client because it still has a reference maintained in the ConnectionList.

If instead my ConnectionList is defined as `typedef std::vector< boost::weak_ptr< connection > > ConnectionList;` then I run the risk of the client disconnecting and nullifying its pointer while somebody is using it from `GetClientList()`.

Anybody have a suggestion on a good & safe way to do this?

Thanks,
PaulH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP is stateless. That means it's difficult to even define what "currently connected client" means, not to mention keeping track of which clients *are* at any given time. The only time there's *really* a "current client" is from the time a request is received to the time that request is serviced (often only a few milliseconds). A connection is not maintained even for the duration of downloading one page -- rather, each item on the page is requested and sent separately.

The typical method for handling this is to use a fairly simple timeout -- a client is considered "connected" for some arbitrary length of time (a few minutes) after they send in a request. A cookie of some sort is used to identify the client sending in a particular request.

The rest of what you're talking about is just a matter of making sure the collection you use to hold connection information is thread safe. You have one thread that adds connections, one thread that deletes them, and N threads that use the data currently in the list. The standard collections don't guarantee any thread safety, but there are others around that do.